# getting an error while Returns a trained trigram tagger :UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x0a'

Tags: python, nlp, pickle

I am having problem in unpickling a .pkl file and editing it. I tried the following code but it shows error. How could I proceed?

```
def trained_tagger(existing=False):
print('checkpoint 8')
"""Returns a trained trigram tagger
existing : set to True if already trained tagger has been pickled
"""
if existing:
    trigram_tagger =  pickle.load(open('D:\\Knowledge Base\\trained_tagger.pkl', 'rb'))

    return trigram_tagger

# Aggregate trained sentences for N-Gram Taggers
train_sents = nltk.corpus.brown.tagged_sents()
train_sents += nltk.corpus.conll2000.tagged_sents()
train_sents += nltk.corpus.treebank.tagged_sents()

# Create instance of SubjectTrigramTagger and persist instance of it
trigram_tagger = SubjectTrigramTagger(train_sents)
pickle.dump(trigram_tagger, open('D:\\Knowledge Base\\trained_tagger.pkl', 'wb'))


return trigram_tagger
```

it shows error as:

```
UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x0a'.
```